# `rails c` or `rake` bloat memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memory

when I try to start `ENV_RAILS=production rails c` (or a `rake` task) some process killer on the server kills the process after a few seconds because it uses more than 400mb of physical memory. Now I need to find out where that bloat comes frome. The server

I know about newrelic and oink - but they seem only to work for server requests - not console or rake tasks. What options are there to investigate on this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I have not used it much but you can try a profiler http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

Heroku suggests that always make the rake, especially if the implementation has many records.
It is not complicated, creating the rakes, create a file. Rake in lib/tasks/clear_cache.rake

```
namespace :admin  do
  desc "Start clear cache"
  task :clear_cache => :environment do
    puts "preparing"
    Rails.cache.clear
    puts "Sucess"
  end
end
```

to run, do the command: "rake clear_cache"
[For more details](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/12/creating-a-custom-rake-task/)